# Pyinstaller - invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error, pyinstaller

I am trying to use pyinstaller to package my script into an exe.

All sources indicate that the correct syntax is: **pyinstaller FullClientCreator.py**

When I issue this command, I get a syntax error:

```
pyinstaller FullClientCreator.py
  File "C:\Users\DAVIDM~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7368/3509825318.py", line 1
    pyinstaller FullClientCreator.py
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried it with the full path for the file, and I still get the same error:

```
pyinstaller "D:\Projects\ZZNew Client CreatorZZ\FullClientCreator.py"
  File "C:\Users\DAVIDM~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7368/546891165.py", line 1
    pyinstaller "D:\Projects\ZZNew Client CreatorZZ\FullClientCreator.py"
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am at a complete loss as to why this could be, so if anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate them.

Comment: `pyinstaller` is a command line tool.. It looks like you're trying to run it from within the ipython kernel.

Answer (score 1):

**Try another shell**

I dont know which shell are you using but if you're using python shell sometimes its not working for python shell so try it on your cmd

> pyinstaller --onefile file.py